# MySQL/Java: Incorrect date value: '1990' for column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've run into a stubborn problem when entering date into MySQL using Java. In my code I am converting a **java.util.Date** to a **java.sql.Date** in order to quick and easy match the SQL formatting for dates.

Below is the code I am using to insert date into the database. *Note: The code is shortened to only express my problem.*

The *client* object is passed through the arguments of the function.

```
        //Date to Date
        java.sql.Date sqlBirthday = new java.sql.Date(client.getBirthday().getTime());

        System.out.println(sqlBirthday); // Prints YYYY-MM-DD

        sql = "INSERT INTO clientdata (client_id, weight, height, birthday) VALUES (" + client.getID() + "," + client.getWeight() + "," + client.getHeight().getMeasurementInInches() + ","
                + sqlBirthday + ")";
        statement.execute(sql);

        statement.close();
```

After executing the code to enter the data into the database, I recieve the following run-time error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1990' for column 'birthday' at row 1

The println outputs the following:

> 1998-05-03

Which is expected output.

The stack trace for the error is below, but I doubt it has much use:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1990' for column 'birthday' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3833)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)
at fitness.traingym.client.utils.DatabaseHandler.createLogin(DatabaseHandler.java:71)
at fitness.traingym.client.TrainManagement.testClientCreate(TrainManagement.java:47)
at fitness.traingym.client.TrainManagement.<init>(TrainManagement.java:22)
at fitness.traingym.client.TrainManagement.main(TrainManagement.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

This is interesting I'm running into this error as the formatting for the date seems to be correct for SQL syntax.

Comment: Birthday is string value, enclose with single quote. Use `sql = "INSERT INTO clientdata (client_id, weight, height, birthday) VALUES (" + client.getID() + "," + client.getWeight() + "," + client.getHeight().getMeasurementInInches() + ",'"
                + sqlBirthday + "')";`

Comment: Short and dangerous answer: put single quotes around the date value. Long and correct answer: use parameterized queries - they're safer (no chance of SQL Injection, which ruins careers and fortunes) and you don't have to worry about date formats or escaping strings with single quotes in them.

Comment: Thank you Ed for the knowledge, I'm fairly new to SQL and haven't been taught Parameterized Queries but after a short bit of looking up after reading your reply I see that it is quite important! Thank you for your response.

Comment: Your problem is not about being new to sql but to Java JDBC framework, but once you learn the basics it will become easier.

Comment: No worries @Mamadou, and you should feel free to experiment with the approach you're taking now if it makes it easier for you to learn. Just make sure that by the time you do this professionally you're using parameterized queries. Best of luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to solve the problem is surrounding the date string with quote `'`, but **this is a nasty trick and MUST BE AVOIDED AT ALL**. The best way to solve this and work with parametrized queries is to use `PreparedStatement`s:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO clientdata (client_id, weight, height, birthday) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInteger(1, client.getID());
pstmt.setInteger(2, client.getWeight());
pstmt.setInteger(3, client.getHeight());
pstmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(client.getBirthday().getTime()));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. Now that I know about parameterized queries I feel like a nubling for not having used them. xD

Comment: I suppose my second question (and I feel the answer is obvious) is: Am I correct in assuming that PreparedStatements should be used in both retrieving and submitting to a database?

Comment: Yes, they're worth for doing both. If you won't pass any parameter to the query, then use `Statement` directly e.g. when performing a DDL statement `CREATE TABLE foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(50))` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the date value needs to be embedded in single quotes (') before being passed in to the database.

Update your Java string to include single quote marks (') around the value of sqlBirthday.

Answer (score 1):

```
String date = request.getParameter("date");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // your template here
java.util.Date dateStr = formatter.parse(sqlBirthday );
java.sql.Date dateDB = new java.sql.Date(dateStr.getTime());
```

Pass it in this java.sql.Date in prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote enclosed in date value

Use

```
sql = "INSERT INTO clientdata (client_id, weight, height, birthday) VALUES (" + client.getID() + "," + client.getWeight() + "," + client.getHeight().getMeasurementInInches() + ", '"+ sqlBirthday + "')";
                                                                                                                                                                                   ^                  ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing SimpleDateFormate to ("yyyy-MM-dd") while setting your DateChooser property format as ("dd-MM-yyyy") worked for me.

Here's an example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dob = sdf.format(BirthDayR.getDate());
    prepareStatement.setString(9, dob);
```

I hope this helped.